# NestedScrollView + CoodinatorLayout scrollBy() scrollTo() methods do nothing

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have a NestedScrollView being used with CoordinatorLayout + AppBarLayout + CollapsingToolbarLayout with parallax effect similar to [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#embedding-google-maps-in-appbarlayout)

I need to scroll the content programmatically (preferably a smooth scroll, i.e. animated), however calling the scroll  methods (scrollBy(), scrollTo(), smoothScrollTo(), smoothScrollBy()) do nothing.

Note that I am using `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` <-- Not sure if the issue is related to this.

I'm calling `nsv_form.smoothScrollBy(0, 300)` in Kotlin when a button is clicked by the user, but nothing happens :(

(Also tried `scrollTo()`, `scrollBy()`, +- 300, all sorts of different variations)

UPDATE: I dug into source code and it seems like the `*scroll*()` methods expect the content of the layout to be larger than the parent view (makes sense).  In my case, the content is smaller, so I suspect that's why the scrolling methods do not work.  Perhaps I need something different instead of `scroll`?

The NestedScrollView's position starts partially off the screen with an image above it in a CollapsingToolbarLayout, [like this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#creating-parallax-animations), so it seems like I need to programmatically move the position of the NestedScrollView AND trigger the CoordinatorLayout's scrolling behavior.  -- How do I do this?

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:src="@drawable/some_image" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nsv_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            [... child views...]

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>    
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**TLDR**: How do I scroll [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFbQh.gif) programmatically?

Comment: I think you should go for scrollview if you have only one child view as there is only one child layout in your case , which is LinearLayout.

Comment: @SumitShukla I tried switching NestedScrollView with ScrollView and it breaks the parallax scrolling behavior (the layout does not scroll at all)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I scroll like this programmatically?

For that scrolling behavior you need collapse or expand `CollapsingToolbarLayout` no need to scroll your the `NestedScrollView`

Here is the sample code for that

Try this  Make some below changes in your Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/goku"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/Boxcolordiabled"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nsv_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/demo" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnColl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Expand " />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/demo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/demo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/demo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/demo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/demo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/demo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/demo" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Activity code

```
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import neel.com.bottomappbar.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    AppBarLayout app_bar;
    Button btnColl;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    CoordinatorLayout rootView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Stack Demo");

        app_bar = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        btnColl = findViewById(R.id.btnColl);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);


        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Collapse FAB Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) app_bar.getLayoutParams();
                final AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();

                if (behavior != null) {
                    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt();
                    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

                    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            behavior.setTopAndBottomOffset((Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                            app_bar.requestLayout();
                        }
                    });

                    valueAnimator.setIntValues(0, -900);
                    valueAnimator.setDuration(1000);
                    valueAnimator.start();
                }
            }
        });

        btnColl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Expand btnColl Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) app_bar.getLayoutParams();
                final AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
                if (behavior != null) {

                    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt();
                    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

                    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            behavior.setTopAndBottomOffset((Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                            app_bar.requestLayout();
                        }
                    });

                    valueAnimator.setIntValues(-900, 0);
                    valueAnimator.setDuration(400);
                    valueAnimator.start();
                }


            }
        });
    }


}
```

**OUTPUT**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZY1zPxjRt0

Comment: Thanks!! This is almost perfect!!  However, I've run into one problem -- the content inside my LinearLayout exceeds the screen height, and this solution stops once the AppBarLayout is fully collapsed. I've tried scrolling the NestedScrollView once AppBarLayout is fully collapsed, however it's not smooth.

`if (appBarLayout.bottom == 0) {
                nsv_form.scrollTo(0, -(animation.animatedValue as Int)) // Also tried smoothScrollTo()
}`  <-- Abrupt animation

Comment: @tenprint check this for the smooth scroll in your `NestedScrollView` https://stackoverflow.com/a/46171939/7666442

Answer (score 1):

Scrolls (`scrollBy()`/`scrollTo()`/`smoothScrollTo()`/`smoothScrollBy()`) needs to be called from **UI thread**.

In Kotlin, you can use

```
Handler().post {
    nsv_form.scrollBy(0, 300)
}
```